# inode-block ratio

Tags: filesystems, inode

How we can find the ratio of inodes to blocks? How can we change that ratio?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question on multiple sites. Your original one can be moved.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ratio, it's going to depend on the filesystem.

On ext2/3/4 then

`tune2fs -l /dev/special`

will display all the paramaters. You'll have to calculate the ratio yourself.

There isn't any way to change the ratio on an existing ext2/3/4 filesystem you have to create a new filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu system:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
```

Will get you this sort of output:

```
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
...
Inode size:           256
```

This assumes you're using an ext2, ext3, or ext4 filesystem. The disk shown is using ext4.